# removeClass ignored while addClass and others work

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have the following line bound to a click event:

```
$(this).parents(".addonoptions").children().removeClass("highlight");
```

It should strip the "highlight" class from the parent's children. But it isn't doing anything.

If I change it to this:

```
$(this).parents(".addonoptions").children().addClass("highlight");
```

Then the highlight class is successfully added to all the children. Likewise, if I change "removeClass" to "hide()" then the selected elements are hid just fine, so I know the correct elements are being selected. I have read numerous other questions and answers about removeClass not working, but none of the answers seem to work in this context.

Here is a basic example of what the HTML looks like, with the "clickme" class being tied to the event above.

```
<div class="addonoptions">
<div><p class="clickme">Click to remove highlights</p></div>
<div class="highlight"><p class="clickme">Click to remove highlights</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the class not applied or are you just not seeing the element's style change?

Comment: need the handler code that `this` refers to

Comment: Andrew - The class is not removed and the style doesn't change.

this refers to the clicked element with the class "clickme".

Comment: original code should have worked fine, suspect something is out of order which makes it all the better to post full handler sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really simplify the removal by simply calling removeClass on the class itself:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hwxj9/

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    /* remove highlight class*/
    $('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    /* or if class exists in other parts of page
       $(this).closest('.addonoptions').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

     */
    /* highlight parent of p */
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');

})
```

Answer (score 1):

`children` only finds immediate children nodes (in this case the `<div>`s instead of the `<p>` tags, use `find` instead.

Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/sKz6y/

Comment: you are defintiely targeting wrong `this` ..look at parents('.addonoptions') in OP code

Comment: Your fiddle is wrong too. There is obviously a click event on the `p`.

Comment: The point of my example was to show the difference between the ```children``` and ```find``` method.  I purposely left the click event out to simplify the answer.

Comment: In my original question I had the highlight on the p elements, but I meant to have it on the divs. I apologize for that. The divs are the ones that have the highlight and need it removed.

Comment: @BryanGentry Then what you have should work.  Could you post an example on jsFiddle showing the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

if `$(this)` is the `<p>` tag then the `children()` call would return the set of `<div>`s. You'll need to use jQuery's `find` method:

Try:

```
$(this).parents(".addonoptions").find('p').removeClass("highlight");
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

---

```
<div class="addonoptions">
    <div>
        <p class="clickme">Click to remove highlights</p>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight">
        <p class="clickme">Click to remove highlights</p>
    </div>
</div>​

$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.addonoptions').children().removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4K7P/

Comment: Sorry, the divs are the ones that are supposed to have highlight removed. I have fixed the html sample in my question to reflect this.

Comment: @BryanGentry your best approach is to debug the code yourself. figure out what `$(this)` is and step through the rest of your code to find the answer ...

Comment: $(this) is the element with the .clickme class which was clicked. I know that I am selecting the right elements because changing removeClass to addClass or any other method applies the changes.